# Configure Groups into springdoc openapi

Tags: springdoc, springdoc-openui

I use this gradle dependency to configue springdoc-openapi:

```
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.7.0'
```

I added:

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfiguration {
    
  @Bean
  public GroupedOpenApi publicApi() {
    return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
            .group("user-api")
            .displayName("user API")
            .packagesToScan("*")
            .pathsToMatch("*", "/admin/.*")
            .build();
  }
}
```

I get when I open `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html#/`

```
No operations defined in spec!
```

I added:

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfiguration {
    
  @Bean
  public OpenAPI springShopOpenAPI() {
    return new OpenAPI()
            .info(new Info().title("HoN Core Auth API")
                    .description("Authentication & authorization API")
                    .version("33")
                    .license(new License().name("(C) HoN")));
  }
}
```

Now I get all endpoints definitions.

Do you know how I can get swagger configuration as groups(displayed into dropdown)?

Comment: Does `pathsToMatch("*", "/admin/.*")` matches any of your endpoints?

Answer (score 3):

Please try the following.

```java
  @Bean
  public GroupedOpenApi publicApi() {
    return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
            .group("user-api")
            .displayName("user API")
            .pathsToMatch("**", "/admin/**")
            .build();
  }
```

Use `**` in pathsToMatch.
If you need regular expressions, you need to specify them like `.paths(PathSelectors.regex("/public.*"))`.

Also, packagesToScan requires you to enter the package name. It can be a root package, but `*` is not available.